# Can't remove "plasma" icon from Plank

Tags: kubuntu, plank

I recently moved to Kubuntu 17.04 from Ubuntu Gnome 17.04, and installed plank on Kubuntu

[image: Screenshot]

This icon does nothing can't be closed or can't be un-pinned

what can I do to remove it?

Comment: I have the same icon running plasma in Arch.  Sometimes the icon changes to a different icon.  It seems as though the a background task is showing up for some reason

Comment: Have you tried stop that task? Did it work out?

Comment: No as Im not sure what task just assuming it's a background task since it cant be closed.  There's an open bug report for this problem on planks bug reports.  go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1650265 and click the affects me to